# How to build a panel that detects both swipe and click events

Tags: javascript, dojo, swipe-gesture

Using **dojo.gesture.swipe** I'd like to be able to listen to any swipe event on a panel and change it's content accordingly:

```
on(myPanel, swipe.end, lang.hitch(this, function(e) {
    if (e.dx < -100) {                      
        //do something
        e.stopPropagation();
        event.stop(e);
    }
}));
```

This piece of code is working fine to detect the swipe event and do something if the swipe movement is big enough.

However on my panel I have other listeners on buttons click that do not work anymore:

```
on(myButton, 'click', lang.hitch(this, 'onMyButtonClick'))`);
```

Any idea what could go wrong ?

Thanxs

Comment: are you using a touch device that would be firing a touch event instead of a click?

Comment: Touch devices generally still emit click events (otherwise the majority of the web would not have worked on them on day one). However, I suspect that dojox.gesture might preventDefault and/or stopPropagation on a lot of events, and if it does that on touchstart, it could prevent click from ever firing.  If you're still talking about touch input specifically, doesn't gesture also have a tap event?

Comment: You are both right. The tap event is the one I needed to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the listener on 'tap' event :

```
on(myButton, tap, lang.hitch(this, onMyButtonClick));
```

That means that when using **dojo.gesture**, one should listen to `click` AND `tap` event if targeting both touch and classic screen.